# MvxTableViewCell loads an empty view

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin, mvvmcross

I needed a custom iOS TableView with different cells depending on the item type. It seemed easy, just define the layouts in the TableViewSource constructor, that is a child of MvxTableViewSource. Registration happens like this:

```
public TableViewSource(UITableView tableView, List<ItemHolder> sections) : base(tableView) {
    tableView.RegisterClassForCellReuse(typeof(MyCell), "MyCellId");
    [Registering further types here]
}
```

To handle sections I've created an ItemHolder that defines the items in the section, and section header/footer. That part works just fine.

In GetOrCreateCellFor, I use the default `DequeueReusableCell` based on the given item's type. However if I register the cell as above, an empty cell is drawn.

My cell uses the XIB+Backing class (based on `MvxTableViewCell`) way, and in theory should work fine. If I use the Nib property of it, and use `RegisterNibForCellReuse`, the content gets drawn (however row heights are wrong, and binding does not happen since it is defined in the backing class).

The class looks like this:

```
public partial class MyCell : MvxTableViewCell
{
    public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString("MyCell");
    public static readonly UINib Nib = UINib.FromName("MyCell", NSBundle.MainBundle);

    protected MyCell(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
        this.DelayBind(() =>
        {
            var binding = this.CreateBindingSet<MyCell, object>();
            binding.Bind(this.TextView.Text).To(vm => vm.GetType().Name).WithConversion(new StringFormatConverter(), "Unknown cell type: {0}");
            binding.Apply();
        });
    }

    public static MyCell Create()
    {
        return (MyCell)Nib.Instantiate(null, null)[0];
    }
}
```

In the XIB I have a UILabelView set up with AutoLayout, that has an Outlet called TextView.

So basically if I add it through the class itself, it does not work at all. If I use the Nib, then layout works, but there are no bindings, datacontext, etc., technically my logic is gone.

Am I doing something wrong here, or this isn't even supposed to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that immediately sticks out is the way your binding is defined. You don't need to Bind `TextView.Text`, you just pass in the TextView:

```
binding.Bind(TextView).To(vm => vm.GetType().Name).WithConversion(new StringFormatConverter(), "Unknown cell type: {0}");
```

That fix might just get everything working for you. Otherwise, this is what works for me in MvvmCross for cell layouts defined in XIB files:

1.) I use `RegisterNibForCellReuse` to register my cells.

2.) Instead of using  `this.DelayBind(() =>` in the constructor. I do my bindings in the `AwakeFromNib` override:

```
public override void AwakeFromNib()
{
    base.AwakeFromNib();

    var binding = this.CreateBindingSet<MyCell, MyCellViewModel>();
    binding.Bind(TextView).To(vm => vm.GetType().Name).WithConversion(new StringFormatConverter(), "Unknown cell type: {0}");
    binding.Apply();
}
```

Comment: My label has a default debug value, so I should see that at least. But the resulting cells are completely empty.

Comment: I've tried moving the binding to AwakeFromNib, but still the same empty cells are drawn. Checking the cells returned, they are indeed the MyCell type, but they are simply not being drawn.

Comment: Okay, I stand corrected. After replacing `RegisterClassForCellReuse` with `RegisterNibForCellReuse`, now it works fine. Apparently iOS logic is completely reversed (Nib, i.e. UI referencing backing code, not code referencing UI).